# Spring Boot FileNotFoundException when getting resource in Docker container

Tags: spring-boot, docker, kotlin

I'm using Docker for Spring boot application. I want to use JSON file to my Google token authentication. While I run this locally on my machine all works perfectly. But when I run this in docker environment I got exception below:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [file.json] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/file.json
```

This `file.json` is located in `/src/main/resources/file.json` to get this file i use code below:

```
@Throws(FileNotFoundException::class, IOException::class)
fun getAccessToken(): AccessToken? {

    val resource =  ClassPathResource("file.json")
    val inputStream: InputStream = resource.inputStream

    val credentials: GoogleCredentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(
        inputStream
    ).createScoped(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/...",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/..."
    )


    return credentials.accessToken
}
```

I've also try to use following method.

```
@Value("classpath:/file.json")
lateinit var resource: Resource

@Throws(FileNotFoundException::class, IOException::class)
fun getAccessToken(): AccessToken? {
   val inputStream: InputStream = resource.inputStream

   val credentials: GoogleCredentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(
            inputStream
        ).createScoped(
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/...",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/..."
        )
```

Both method throws the same exception. Would appreciate any comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code below worked for me:

```
val credentials: GoogleCredentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(
            this.javaClass.getResourceAsStream("/file.json")
        ).createScoped(
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/...",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/..."
        )
```

For some reason if i pass `inputStream` as variable it doesn't work. If somebody have any idea why I will appreciate that.